# Echo something from a tmux session to base session

Tags: tmux, session, sleep

I have a script with this code:

```
#!/bin/bash
tmux new-session -d bash
    sleep 1d
    echo 1 day passed
    tmux kill-session
```

AFAIU, the echo will appear after 24 hours in the tmux session's stdout but not in my basic Bash session (the session I have after booting my operating system).

How could I make sure that the echo from the tmux session (which is ofcourse one layer above my basic Bash session), would be printed in my basic session?

The purpose is to utilize the `sleep` time phase **in another** session but to have output from all commands coming under it **in my** session.

<sub>Ofcourse, I can't use sleep in my base session because it would make the session unusable or "sleepy".</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the echo will appear after 24 hours in the `tmux` session's stdout

If you refer to the `tmux` session you start from the script, then this is not true. `bash` process executing the script will wait for `tmux new-session -d bash` to exit, then it will execute `sleep 1d` and so on. Notice `tmux new-session -d bash` exits almost immediately because of `-d` (the other `bash` within the newly created `tmux` session doesn't exit but it's irrelevant now).

Change the delay to `sleep 10` and run the script. Wait a while and you will see it `echo`-es to your *current* terminal. Next invoke `tmux ls` to see there's a new useless session left behind. You may attach to it and verify nothing was `echo`-ed there.

---

> I can't use `sleep` in my base session because it would make the session unusable

So does your script, while running in foreground. How about a background job? You don't need `tmux` at all:

```
(sleep 20s; echo surprise) &
```

---

In general you *can* write to another terminal, if only you have proper permissions. The following is what I can do in my Debian. Let's say I want to write from session B, so the text is visible in `bash` session A. First I need to know what device the `stdout` of A actually is:

```
readlink /proc/$pid_of_bash_A/fd/1
```

From within the `bash` A this is simpler thanks to `$$` special parameter:

```
readlink /proc/$$/fd/1
```

The output is `/dev/pts/3` in my case. Then in the session B:

```
echo Hello World! > /dev/pts/3
```